# Issue with template and inheritances

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

I am trying to make all my classes to be generic.But the issue arose with class Circle and the ones following right after it.Where am I making a mistake?

It seems to work when I exchange them for "int". But that seems to fail my original needs of having the classes be generic.

```
class DrawableObject
{
    public:
    virtual void print()=0;
};

template <typename T>
class Point : public DrawableObject
{

    T x;T y;

    public:
        Point()
        {   x=0;
            y=0;
        }
        Point(T a)
        {   x=a;
            y=a;
        }
        Point(T a,T b)
        {   x=a;
            y=b;
        }
        void setX(T newX)
        {   
            x=newX;
        }
        void setY(T newY)
        {   
            y=newY;
        }
        T getX()
        {   return x;
        }
        T getY()
        {   return y;}
        void print()
        {   cout<<"(X,Y) Coordinates are ("<<x<<","<<y<<")"<<endl;}
};

template <typename U>
class Rectangle : public Point<U>
{


    U width,height;

    public:
        Rectangle()
        {   width=0;
            height=0;
        }
        Rectangle(U a)
        {   width=a;
            height=a;
        }
        Rectangle(U a,U b)
        {   width=a;
            height=b;
        }       
        void setWidth(U newWidth)
        {   width=newWidth;}
        void setHeight(U newHeight)
        {   height=newHeight;}
        U getHeight()
        {   return height;}
        U getWidth()
        {   return width;}
        void print()
        {   cout<<"Rectangle is of area "<<width<<"X"<<height<<endl;}
};
```

Issue arises from here onwards

```
template <typename V>
class Circle : public Point<V>
{

    V radius;

    public:
        Circle():Point()
        {   
            radius=0;
        }
        Circle(V a):Point(a)
        {   
            radius=a;
        }
        Circle(V a,V b,V c):Point(a,b)
        {   
            radius=c;
        }
        void setRadius(V newRadius)
            {radius=newRadius;}
        V getRadius()
            {return radius;}
        void print()
            {cout<<"Circle with centre at  ("<<getX()<<","<<getY()<<") and of radius "<<radius<<endl;}
};
```

Error appears like this one below.

```
oops_case_study.cpp: In constructor ‘Circle<V>::Circle()’:
oops_case_study.cpp:81:12: error: class ‘Circle<V>’ does not have any field named ‘Point’
   Circle():Point()
            ^~~~~
```

Comment: That's `Point<V>`.

Comment: Have you tried Point<V> since that is what you inherited? You are also missing ~Point() and ~Circle() I think.

Comment: Not your immediate problem, but please note that LSP is violated by this kind of inheritance quite often.  Rectangles *have* points, Circles *have* points; saying a Rectangle *is a* point is usually wrong.  Similarly, an immutable Square *is a* Rectangle, but a mutable Square is not a mutable Rectangle (a reasonable post condition on changing width of a rectangle is that its' height is unchanged; for a square, this doesn't hold).

Answer (score 0):

When you call the base class constructor from the derived constructor you also need to specify the template parameter for the bases class, like below.

```
    Circle() : Point<V>()
    {   
        radius=0;
    }
```

note that Point's constructor is called like `Point<V>()`